# Sorting list of strings alphabetically ignoring vowels python

Tags: python, string, list, sorting

If I have a list of strings, how would I sort it alphabetically by ignoring vowels. For example, ['alpha', 'beta'] would sort to ['beta', 'alpha'], because 'bt' is alphabetically before 'lph'. I've tried it a bit using lambda functions and stuff, but I am a bit stuck, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Someone's doing the NCSS python challenge haha

Comment: @that2guy exactly

Comment: Exact question. :) haha

Answer (score 3):

You can use a lambda function in the key parameter of sorted function.

```
In [14]: l = ['alpha', 'beta']
In [15]: v = {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'}
In [16]: sorted(l, key=lambda item: [char for char in item if char.lower() not in v])
Out[16]: ['beta', 'alpha']
```

Comment: Nice, was about to hackt that, too. I would use a set for the vowels, since they will not change much

Comment: @ChristianSauer Yes, set is more effective.

Answer (score 2):

In Python 2.x, you may use [`string.translate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.translate) within lambda to remove the vowels from the string as:

```
>>> my_list = ['alpha', 'beta', 'gamma', 'theta']
>>> vowels = 'aeiouAEIOU' # string of 'vowel'

>>> sorted(my_list, key=lambda s: s.translate(None, vowels))
['beta', 'gamma', 'alpha', 'theta']
```

But in Python 3.x, you need to firstly convert the string to byte in order to access the `translate` function. for example:

```
sorted(my_list, key=lambda s: s.encode.translate(None, b'aeiouAEIOU')
# Note: This will work on Python 2.x as well, but encoding is not required there
```

As an alternative, you also use the below *lambda expression* within the `sorted` which will work fine on both Python 2.x and 3.x:

```
sorted(my_list, key=lambda s: ''.join(c for c in s if c not in vowels))
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a good idea to use a named function here. There are two benefits - you can use a descriptive name, and you've got a function that can be unit tested.

```
def remove_vowels_from_string(s):
    return s.translate(None, 'aeiouAEIOU')

new_list = sorted(my_list, key=remove_vowels_from_string)
```

For Python3, you can use this version

```
def remove_vowels_from_string(s):
    return translate(dict.fromkeys(map(ord, 'aeiouAEIOU')))

new_list = sorted(my_list, key=remove_vowels_from_string)
```